# How is struct "HashCode" actually implemented? (not found at referencesource.microsoft com)

Tags: c#

How is struct HashCode implemented? (no hit at referencesource.microsoft)

Why cannot it be found at referencesource.microsoft.com? (btw same applies for Path.Join...)

```
new HashCode.Add(T value)
new HashCode().ToHashCode()

HashCode.Combine(T1 value1, T2 value2, etc.)
```

Poor decompilation result by resharper:

```
public partial struct HashCode
    {
        private int _dummyPrimitive;
        public void Add<T>(T value) { }
        public void Add<T>(T value, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) { }
        public static int Combine<T1>(T1 value1) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2>(T1 value1, T2 value2) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4, T5 value5) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4, T5 value5, T6 value6) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4, T5 value5, T6 value6, T7 value7) { throw null; }
        public static int Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(T1 value1, T2 value2, T3 value3, T4 value4, T5 value5, T6 value6, T7 value7, T8 value8) { throw null; }
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.ObsoleteAttribute("HashCode is a mutable struct and should not be compared with other HashCodes.", true)]
        public override bool Equals(object obj) { throw null; }
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.ObsoleteAttribute("HashCode is a mutable struct and should not be compared with other HashCodes. Use ToHashCode to retrieve the computed hash code.", true)]
        public override int GetHashCode() { throw null; }
        public int ToHashCode() { throw null; }
    }
```

Comment: It won't be on reference source as it's that looks like the .net core signature? So [System.HashCode](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/HashCode.cs)?

Comment: check `EqualityComparer` it has `GetHashCode()` implementation. might be useful for you

Comment: referencesource.microsoft is for .NET framework stuff. For .NET Core, check out source.dot.net. For example, [HashCode](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,5f9e3dc86db22de1).